# A word for "Painful Anticipation"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to use in this context...

A teacher is scheduled to teach English 100. He has taught it before and knows it to be a grind. He believes that, like always, it will be populated by students who have built up a healthy disdain for English. So, he is sitting in his office minutes before the class begins feeling *painful anticipation* over his first lecture.

Psychology uses "[Negative Anticipation](http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2009/04/06/negative-anticipation-set-up-for-worry/)" for these moments. I am hoping for a single word. The closest word I've found is "pang", but it sounds incomplete without "of something."

So, I would like a word that signifies *the painful looking forward to an undesirable inevitability*. This isn't a feeling of fear, just discomfort at knowing that what's to come will be arduous and tedious.

Comment: Dread. This is a general reference question.

Comment: @MετάEd: When someone dreads something, my first reaction is that they are afraid of it for some reason. I might ask them what there is to fear in the thing. I realize that this isn't always the case with dread, but I was hoping for a word that disambiguates between fear and displeasure.

Comment: Dread is the right word. It has the two connotations of fear and displeasure. Context usually disambiguates for the listener. There are no one-word verbs that mean only "do not look forward to because the idea repels me", unless it's the passive use of repel: "I'm repelled by having to teach English 100 again next semester".

Comment: While "dread" is the low-hanging fruit, one word does not a rich language make!  Let's flex a little linguistic muscle here!

Comment: @BillFranke: I agree that dread works if context is clear. Best option, so far. Ugly word, though, dread.

Answer (score 1):

There are many words that tap into that feeling to a certain degree (though they all share the basic emotion of dread at some level)

- Foreboding (my favorite!)
- Trepidation
- Apprehension
- Consternation
- Unease

Comment: Consternation seems best here, & it's a verb, so one can say "Having to teach English 100 next semester consternates me". Howsomever, it's ambiguous: "to fill with dismay or astonishment" (MW3UDE), which leaves us between the same Scylla & Charybdis. The other choices don't remove the fear, & "unease" doesn't express the displeasure. Maybe "Having to teach English 100 next semester {repels / annoys / displeases (and all its synonyms)} me" is okay.